# Sass more than one selector at the root and individual style for each from inside along with common style for all

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a style like so-

```
button,
a.button,
input[type="button"] {
    color: red;
}

button {
    border: none;
}

a {
    .button {
        border: 1px solid purple;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to combine them all into one declaration by nesting them?